# How to profile boot time methods in android using ddms?

Tags: android, profiling, ddms

I need to profile methods on boot for my android app. I know to profile programatically, but just wondering whether we can do the same using DDMS(or similar tools).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you help me do profiling programatically ? Is there any blogpsot which I can refer to ? Can you publish a post with an example on how to do profiling programatically in android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try BootChart - it's easy to use and quite accurate (of course, measuring takes time and alters boot time).

More here: http://embien.com/blog/android-boot-time-optimization-tools-analysis/.